# Runtime error occurred when accessing a generic method of an element in a list

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class A<T> {
  final T data;
  final T Function(T) convert;

  A(this.convert, this.data);

  Type get genericType => T;
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  final list = <A>[
    A<int>((i) => i + i, 0),
    A<String>((i) => i + i, '0'),
  ];

  print(list[0].data);    // ok
  print(list[0].convert); // runtime error: type '(int) => int' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'
}
```

It seems that dart thinks the Function type is not compatible.
But why does this happen at runtime and how should i solve it without losing the advantage of compile time type checking.

**Edit:**

I found that if I upcast the element before reading this function, it will be ok:

```dart
final first = list[0] as A<int>;
print(first.convert); // ok
```

So I want to find a way to upcast the element at runtime dynamically.
I added a method to get the actual generic type of class A according
to other stackoverflow answers.

```dart
Type get genericType => T;
```

It would be nice if i can do this:

```dart
final t = list[0].genericType;
final first = list[0] as A<t>;
print(first.convert);
```

Unfortunately I can't. As a dirty workaround, If I have a limited number of generics I can do something like this:

```dart
  final t = list[0].genericType;
  if (t == int) {
    final first = list[0] as A<int>;
    print(first.convert);
  } else if (t == String) {
    final first = list[0] as A<String>;
    print(first.convert);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening, because the list has been declared to be of type `List<A>` which is equivalent to `List<A<dynamic>>`. This leads to the compiler type-checking everything for `dynamic`.

```
print(list[0].data);    // compiler inferred: dynamic
print(list[0].convert); // compiler inferred: (dynamic) => dynamic
```

At run time, the second expression becomes a problem. The object is actually of type `(int) => int`, enforcing an `int` input to the function instead of accepting any subtype of `dynamic` as expected by the compiler. This contradiction between what the compiler thinks and what the runtime says then leads to the exception being thrown.

---

Unfortunately, there is no real way to solve solve this apart from rewriting this whole construct. Dart is centered around this mechanism of type inference and the moment you cast the list to `A<dynamic>` the compiler lose out on a lot of information.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `A<int>` `convert` becomes `int Function (int)`;
Declaring `A<String>` `convert` becomes `String Function (String)`;
For some reason Dart do looking the `T` parameter of `convert` method as a `dynamic` and as for it are telling you the parameter type doesn’t match (Personally I’m agree with your programming approach and I hope this can be resolved in a 'direct cast conversion' in a future release of Dart).

However to resolve your problem you can simply do:

Declaring convert  as:

```
  final T Function(dynamic) convert;
```

Or without any change on A convert the parameter type in dynamic here:

```
  final List<A> list = <A>[
    A<int>((dynamic i) => i + i, 0),
    A<String>((dynamic i) => i + i, '0'),
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using this workaround, too.